# Prove or Disprove $\int _{a}^{b} fg = 0$ where, f and g are reimann Integrable on [a,b] such that $\int _{a}^{b} f^2 = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

I understand how to prove if the function f and g were to be continuous. But, what about when the point of discontinuity is negligible set?

I feel like, If I somehow prove that $f(x) = 0$ $\forall$ $ x\in[a,b]-S$
where, $S$ is the set of discontinuity of $f$ in [a,b]

Then, $fg(x)=0$ $\forall$ $x\in[a,b]-S$
$\implies$$\int _{a}^{b} fg = 0$

Comment: **Riemann** please! With a capital **R**. (It is a *name:* [Georg Friedrich Bernhard Riemann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernhard_Riemann).)

Comment: I am sorry my intention was not to disrespect him. I miss-typed .

Comment: Have you heard of Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? $\left|\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx\right|^2\le\int_a^bf(x)^2 dx\cdot\int_a^bg(x)^2 dx$

Comment: No, I am new to Riemann Integral. And, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Look it up. The proof is quite simple (consider that for every $\lambda\in\mathbb R$ we have $\int_a^b(f(x)-\lambda g(x))^2dx\ge 0$, reorder the expression on the left side to be a quadratic in $\lambda$, so its discriminant is $\le 0$ - out pops the inequality.)

Comment: See if  [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1889457/841303) helps.